# Java: Token rearrangement and character removal with text file

Tags: java, regex, loops, java.util.scanner

I am trying to take a text file which has a list of peoples first and last names with age and rearrange it so the console output would go from `46 Richman, Mary A.` to `Mary A. Richman 46`. However, in my attempt to do so I have ran into issues (shown below) and I don't understand exactly why they're occurring (it was much worse earlier).

I'd really appreciate the assistance!

Text File:

```
75 Fresco, Al
67 Dwyer, Barb
55 Turner, Paige
108 Peace, Warren
46 Richman, Mary A.
37 Ware, Crystal
83 Carr, Dusty
15 Sledd, Bob
64 Sutton, Oliver
70 Mellow, Marsha
29 Case, Justin
35 Time, Justin
8 Shorts, Jim
20 Morris, Hugh
25 Vader, Ella
76 Bird, Earl E.
```

My Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("people.txt"));
        while (input.hasNext()) { // Input == people.txt
            String line = input.next().replace(",", "");
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            int age = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(firstName + lastName + age);

        }
    }
}
```

Bad Console Output: (How is it throwing an Unknown Source Error?)

```
Fresco,Al67
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Ex2.main(Ex2.java:11)
```

Target Console Output:

```
Al Fresco 75
Barb Dwyer 67
Paige Turner 55
Warren Peace 108
Mary A. Richman 46
Crystal Ware 37
Dusty Carr 83
Bob Sledd 15
Oliver Sutton 64
Marsha Mellow 70
Justin Case 29
Justin Time 35
Jim Shorts 8
Hugh Morris 20
Ella Vader 25
Earl E. Bird 76
```

Comment: use input.nextLine().replace(",", "")

Comment: you should really take the entire line split it around whitespace then take each piece as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make sure the first name includes the middle initial

```
while (input.hasNext()) 
{
    String[] line = input.nextLine().replace(",", "").split("\\s+");
    String age = line[0];
    String lastName = line[1];
    String firstName = "";
    //take the rest of the input and add it to the last name
    for(int i = 2; 2 < line.length && i < line.length; i++)
        firstName += line[i] + " ";

    System.out.println(firstName + lastName + " " + age);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issue and simplify the logic by actually reading with `input.nextLine()` as shown in the below code with comments:

```
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = input.nextLine();//read next line

      line = line.replace(",", "");//replace , 
      line = line.replace(".", "");//replace .

      String[] data = line.split(" ");//split with space and collect to array

      //now, write the output derived from the split array
      System.out.println(data[2] + " " + data[1] + " " + data[0]);
}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed and that I was don't get is how can you get the middle initial with its period to move?

Comment: `line.replace(".", "")` will do that as shown above